# Baby gift suggestion for third boy?

Tags: newborn, presents

What is a good idea for a baby gift for someone who has just had their third boy? They do not want to see one more blue stretchie :) - or even any piece of boy's clothing. They have toys and books, hooded towels and snowsuits, a high chair and mobile and bouncer etc. Any ideas?

Comment: You can never have enough books!

Answer (score 3):

If it were me receiving the gift, I would find a gift card to WalMart or a grocery store or some place equally ubiquitous the most useful gift.  We received several gift cards to Target when my daughter was born and they were so nice to have on hand when I turned out to need lots more newborn clothes than I expected or for diapers or for whatever.  Even if they cloth diaper, they'll need detergent and other general essentials that you just run out of periodically.

Comment: +1 though I'd probably favor the more generic gift cards (like the Visa or AmEx cards) that are good for a number of different places, unless you know they shop at a particular store. That way, they can use the card at their preferred store, instead of at the one the giver chose.

Comment: Visa and AmEx cards are fine, but also usually have fees associated with them with can be annoying for giver and givee alike.

Comment: The **gift cards** don't usually have fees (Visa doesn't mention any, AmEx charges a couple of dollars for the purchase, but has no fees after that), but the **prepaid cards** might, so make sure you know which one you're getting. The difference is that prepaid cards are reloadable, while gift cards generally aren't.

Answer (score 3):

A gift certificate to a spa. With three boys, mom'll probably need it. ;)

More seriously, though, unless it's consumables (diapers, detergents, etc) or gift cards/certificates to buy what they need, the family probably has everything they need from the first two (assuming the third was planned, or close enough to 2 that they didn't get rid of everything), so get creative and/or buy for the parents instead of the kids.

A gift certificate to a spa or a bed and breakfast, then, would probably be a welcome gift, especially if it also comes with a babysitting offer. "Gift certificates" for things like babysitting, house cleaning, or whatever else you can do to help the family would probably be welcome, too.

If you're the crafty sort, a homemade quilt or knitted/crocheted blanket may also make a nice gift (just make sure they know you expect them to *use* it).

If you're still set on getting a gift specifically for the baby, go with stuff that would be his alone, and unlikely to have something like it passed down from his brothers for sentimental reasons, such as a blankie or "lovey".

Comment: +1 for the spa combined with babysitting - it's not a joke but a seriously good idea!

Answer (score 2):

I found a few things useful for new parents with multiple kids.

a gift certificate to macy's or lord and taylor or something so the mom can get herself something

a picture frame with the same number of spots as there are kids.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want anyone to give us clothes, books or any furniture (crib/mattress/bouncer/high chair) for our second baby girl either. However, the things that we did go and purchase:

- **Diapers**. They are still going to need diapers for the child. If they are using cloth diapers, you can buy some cloth diaper detergent.
- **Food**. Formula if they use it. Otherwise, few items of baby food would do good. If they usually puree their own food, go for something like rice cereals.
- **Teething toys** are generally appreciated as they see a lot of use.
- **Baby plates, spoons, and forks** are generally misplaced or lost, so you might consider those.
- **Snack cups and water cups** for the child to take in the car (when he is older) might be necessary, depending on the ages of the other children.

The new little one might also need its own pacifier and soft blanket. If your friends didn't get a **baby carrier** earlier, they might try one now.

Also consider: baby sitting or a dinner and movie gift certificate would be great presents for parents of three children.